# How can I get this to work : "WorkersText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Workers");"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a text object in my game called WorkersText.
I am creating a save / load script for my game so the player can save and load their progress.

Originally I dragged the Text Object to the Object Inspector, but after the player loads the save point, it removes it from there. The same happened with general GameObjects, so I added a line to assign it in Start(). eg `ObjectManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ObjectManager");`

Now I need to do the same with my Text objects but it wont let me do `WorkersText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Workers");`

I get the error that Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'

So I assume FindGameObjectWithTag is off the table. Is there any other way to refrence the Text via code? Sadly as mensioned before, I cannot simply drag the Text object into the Object Inspector.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't put code in the question's _title._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `GameObject` as a result and obviously cannot assign it to the `Text` type variable. That is what error is about. Add `GetComponent<Text>()` to the object returned. If it has such a component - you will get your `Text` to assign.

Comment: Thank you! I did `WorkersText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Workers").GetComponent<Text>();` and it worked perfectly. :)